# Chrome browser shows picture in wrong size

Tags: google-chrome, resize, png, blur

I am confused. I use a PNG image on my website. When I display this image without CSS (https://www.smart-rechner.de/assets/pics/rechner/erbschaftsteuer.png), the image appears blurred. The browser shows the image size (670x600) in the title. I use the chrome zoom level 100%. But the picture is displayed larger and is therefore blurred. If I save it as a screenshot with "Print", it becomes an image of 785 x 700 px. I suspect this is due to my screen resolution. Does anyone know this behaviour from Chrome?

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example. That will make it much easier to help you. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: This problem does happen for me in Chromium 95 and higher, but doesn't in Chromium 68 — both started with empty config. In my case the problem apparently is that I have 102×102 DPI screen, so for some reason Chromium upscales all the images by 6.25% (the ratio of 102/96). I don't know how to fix it other than faking screen settings to the browser.

Comment: In my case it was Windows display scaling 125%